# How to make changes in XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a xml file

MC.xml contents of which are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MCOO type="list">

    <AAA>
        <Active value="True" li="True" mv="True"/>
        <Plot value="True" li="False" mv="False"/>
        <Color value="#990000"/>

    </AAA>

    <BBB>
        <Active value="True" li="True" mvl="True"/>
        <Plot value="True" li="False" mvl="False"/>
        <Color value="#990000"/>


    </BBB>

    <CCC>
        <Active value="True" li="False" mv="True"/>
        <Plot value="False" li="False" mv="False"/>
        <Color value="#990000"/>

    </CCC>
    
</MCOO>
```

I have a list lets say

kk = ['AAA', 'CCC']

So i want to change the Active value, part to True/False if the element is in the list.

I checked out some videos but was not able to parse the contents properly to access the Active values. can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the build in `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

kk = ['AAA', 'CCC']

for elem in root:
    if elem.tag in kk:
        for active in elem.iter():
            if active.tag == "Active":
                var = active.get('value')
                #print(var)
                if var == 'True':
                    active.set('value', 'False')
                else:
                    active.set('value', 'True')
                    
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<MCOO type="list">
  <AAA>
    <Active value="False" li="True" mv="True" />
    <Plot value="True" li="False" mv="False" />
    <Color value="#990000" />
  </AAA>
  <BBB>
    <Active value="True" li="True" mvl="True" />
    <Plot value="True" li="False" mvl="False" />
    <Color value="#990000" />
  </BBB>
  <CCC>
    <Active value="False" li="False" mv="True" />
    <Plot value="False" li="False" mv="False" />
    <Color value="#990000" />
  </CCC>
</MCOO>
```